# Kotlin Vert.x Postgres pub/sub not working

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, vert.x

I am trying to implement Postgres pub/sub in a Kotlin Vert.x app, but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is what I've tried:

````
    public override suspend fun start() {
        val subscriber = PgSubscriber.subscriber(
            Vertx.vertx(), PgConnectOptions()
                .setPort(5432)
                .setDatabase("postgres")
                .setHost("localhost")
                .setUser("postgres")
        )

        val connect = subscriber.connect { ar: AsyncResult<Void?> ->
            if (ar.succeeded())
                println(ar.result())
                subscriber.channel("added_workspace_request")
                .handler { payload: String -> println("Received $payload") }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Be more clear, what is not working it is always useful to provide error log

Answer (score 0):

Did you send the `listen $channel` sql statement on the connection?